# NodeJS - Spawn function

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, batch-file, child-process

I'm working with nodejs and the child process module to execute commands on my platform. To do that, I use the [spawn function](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Here's my code:

```
var spawn_execution = executor.spawn(command, args);

spawn_execution.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

spawn_execution.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Nothing fancy. So I tried a couple of commands that worked like

```
executor.spawn('C:/path/to/ffmpeg.exe', [...]);
```

But when I try to use a native windows command, it does not work. For instance, I tried:

```
executor.spawn('del', ['C:\\my\\file\\to\\delete']);
```

When executing this, I've got a ENOENT error which means that the file is not found. So I did another thing:

```
executor.spawn('C:/my/script-delete.exe', ['C:\\my\\file\\to\\delete']);
```

This script-delete.exe just contains:

```
del %1
```

So why does the spawn function need to have a script file? Why does it not work with native windows command? Do you know a way to make it work with a native command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work as the internal commands can't be found from `executor.spawn` only `cmd.exe` knows them.

So it works from a batch file or when you use something like

```
executor.spawn('cmd.exe', ['/C', 'del', 'C:\\my\\file\\to\\delete']);
```